# PhantomJS's limit for PNG generation with an Hightchart JSON document(3DOption enable)

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

We have this JSON document (Hightcharts chart) with 3D options disabled http://pastebin.com/0rvW3cu3)

The PNG generation with PhantomJS works without any problem.
With the 3D option enabled,the PNG generation do not work anymore

I dont think it's a syntax error, my other documents works with 3D enabled.

There is only one difference between those two documents which is :

3D enabled :
`options3d:{enabled: true, alpha: 0, beta: 0, depth: 50}}`

3D disabled :
`options3d:{enabled:false} (3D disabled)`

The document has 48.000 characters
I use PhantomJS as a local server and I use POST requests to communicate with
Is there a maximum size of a JSON document handled by PhantomJS ?

**Edit :**

I use this format of data to hide 0 value : {y:0,  dataLabels:{enabled:false}}

When my first data of my graphics is `{y:0,  dataLabels:{enabled:false}}`, the data graphics is not displayed.

Fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/24qvky06/):

if you modify the first data "1" to {y:0,  dataLabels:{enabled:false}} the graphic doesn't works

Comment: Have your tried posting to PhanthomJS a larg (over 48k characters) with 3D disabled? (To check if it is a JSON limit issue)

Comment: Apparently it's not a JSON limit. I add some data and it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is makes your chart throw [error #12](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/12)

> Highcharts expects point configuration to be numbers or arrays in turbo mode

This can be solved by setting turboThreshold to 0 (turn it off).
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/24qvky06/1/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold: 0
        }
    },
```

API reference for turboThreshold: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold